# Proving the Beltrami-Laplacian of $S^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I am trying to show that for $S^2$ with the standard metric,
$$\Delta_{S^2}x^1 = -2x^1$$

where $\Delta_{S^2}x^1$ is the Beltrami-Laplacian of $S^2$ and $x^1$ is the restriction of the coordinate function $x^1$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $S^2$.

So, I also know that if I have a function $f$, then $\Delta f = \text{div}(\nabla f)$.

Though, I am not really sure how to make the connection between this Beltrami-Laplacian of $S^2$ and the $-2x^1$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3518279/8157) will surely be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you to you both! Yes, I believe it does.