# What spherical functions can the N-th order limited spherical harmonics represent?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, approximation-theory, orthogonal-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

**Background**

It is known that the spherical harmonics $Y_n^m$ with order $n$ and degree $m$ (such that $n \ge 0, -n \le m \le n$) are functions on the sphere which form a complete, orthogonal infinite set in $L^2$ space on the sphere surface $S^2$.

Given any arbitrary square-integrable function $f(\theta, \phi) \in L^2(S^2)$, the spherical Fourier series with coefficients for order $n \le N$, denoted $S_N(f)$ converges absolutely in the 2-norm:

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \lVert f - S_N(f) \rVert_2 = 0
$$

For a finite, $N$-th order limited set of spherical harmonics, what functions can be exactly represented (in the norm convergence sense)?

Consider the spherical function:
$$
f(\theta, \phi) = \cos(2 \phi) \sin \theta
$$

[image: The function f in a colatitude spherical coordinate system]

Due to the identities:
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{e^{i \theta} + e^{-i \theta}}{2}, \quad \sin \theta = \frac{e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}}{2i}
$$
it appears that $f(\theta, \phi)$ is a 2nd-order trigonometric polynomial, as one would conclude for a 1-dimensional function $g(x)$ with a traditional Fourier series [(source)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/trigonometric-series/trigonometric-series/D3C181B8F0AA3FFCBCD4CA62C2CEF862):
$$
S_\infty (g) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n x}
$$
which is equal to:
$$
c_0 + (c_1 e^{ix} + c_{-1} e^{-ix}) + \ldots + (c_n e^{inx} + c_{-n} e^{-inx}) + \ldots
$$
and we know that $e^{\pm i n \theta} = \cos (n \theta) \pm i \sin (n \theta)$. I think this expresses a relation between the trigonometric functions and the complex exponential, where order is the multiple of the dependent variable. I would assert that: *the SHs are just this process in two dimensions*. Therefore, the SHs of order 2 can exactly represent trig polynomials of order 2, regardless of whether it is in $\theta$ or $\phi$.

But I must be missing some crucial theory. Numerically, I can determine that there are SH coefficients that are non-zero beyond the 2nd-order:

[image: Spherical harmonic coefficients using ACN numbering]

Coefficients corresponding to order 2 and below are to the left of the red dashed line. (The ACN channel numbering is from Ambisonics to identify the specific SH coefficient according to $n^2 + n + m$.)

**So the questions are:** why can't the spherical harmonics of order $n \le 2$ represent $f(\theta, \phi)$? And furthermore, what exactly can they represent in terms of orders of polynomials? What math theory am I missing?

Comment: What are polynomials on $S^2$? Restrictions of polynomials on the ambient $\mathbb R^3$ to the unit sphere?

Comment: @doetoe Polynomials that are functions of $(\theta, \phi)$. I think it is correct to call them homogeneous polynomials. An example would be a spherical harmonic, i.e. $Y_4^3(\theta, \phi) = -\sqrt{315/64 \pi} \cos \theta \sin^3 \theta\, e^{3 i \phi}$. I only have a cursory knowledge of the concepts, sorry.

Comment: But the spherical harmonic you list above, a pretty typical one, is not a polynomial over $\theta$ and $\phi$, so it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: I've come across the wikipedia article on trigonometric interpolation, and I think this might be more relevant. The essence of my question is about whether spherical harmonics of order $n \le N$ can perfectly represent functions sampled at $(N+1)^2$ points uniformly on the sphere. And then the question about squaring follows. I will try to reword my question.

Comment: Some clarification is necessary. In your comment above, you said that $Y_4^3$ is a polynomial in $\theta$ and $\phi$, but really, it's a polynomial in $\cos\theta$, and $e^\phi$. Is that what you mean?  Because if that's the case, then I think the answer is a pretty clear (to me) yes (because the $Y^lm$'s are just associated Legendre polynomials of $\cos\theta$ mutiplied by powers of $e^i\phi$).  But if you actually mean polynomials of $\theta$ and $\phi$, then $Y^m_n$ is *not* an example of such a polynomial, and in general my guess it that the answer is no.

Comment: @march Are they not effectively the same though? For example, $\cos^n \theta$ and $\cos (n \theta)$ both have identities in terms of $\exp\{i n \theta\}$. Does this not make them equivalent, plus or minus other terms that certainly do not contain higher orders of exponential powers?

Comment: I've tried to improve the question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, I mean, when I hear "polynomials of $\theta$ and $\phi$", I picture something like $\theta^3\phi^2 + 3\theta+1$, but what I think you mean is polynomials $x^3y^2+x+1$, where $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=e^{i\phi}$.  Is that right? That's the clarification I'm talking about. But I think your post edit clarified that.

Comment: I think the problem with $\cos(2\phi)\sin(\theta)$ is that it corresponds to a state with $m>l$ ($m=2$, $l=1$), but the spherical harmonics restrict to $m\leq l$.  It seems, then, that the spherical harmonics are not the generalizations of trigonometric polynomials that you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of polar, let us work in Cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)\in\mathbb R^3$, with the constraint that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. You are representing functions on the sphere as $f=f(\theta, \phi)$, but we can equivalently represent them as functions of $(x, y, z)$ via the following change of coordinates formulas (physicist's convention):
$$\tag{1}
\begin{cases}
x=\sin\theta \cos \phi, \\
y=\sin\theta\sin\phi, \\
z=\cos \theta.
\end{cases}$$
The usefulness of this lies in the following.

**Fact.** The function $Y=Y(\theta, \phi)$ is a spherical harmonic of degree $n$ if and only if, letting
$$
Y(\theta, \phi)=H(x, y, z), $$
the function $H$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ and moreover
$$
\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial y^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial z^2} =0,\qquad \forall (x, y, z)\in \mathbb R^3.$$
Notice that this last equation must hold for all $(x, y, z)\in\mathbb R^3$, not just on the sphere. In other words, $H$ must be a *harmonic homogeneous polynomial*.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3518279/8157) there is a proof of this fact.

**Examples** of homogeneous harmonic polynomials $H=H(x, y, z)$ of various degrees are
$$
x,\quad y,\quad z,\quad x^2-z^2, $$
which, using (1), yield the following spherical harmonics in polar coordinates:
$$
\sin\theta  \cos\phi,\quad \sin\theta\sin\phi,\quad \cos\theta,\quad\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi-\cos^2\theta.$$

**We conclude** from all this that, in particular, every linear combination of spherical harmonics of degree up to $N$ must be a harmonic polynomial in the Cartesian coordinates of degree up to $N$.

---

Now let us consider the example given above, namely
$$
f(\theta, \phi)=\cos(2\phi)\sin(\theta).$$
Using (1), we see that
$$
\begin{split}
f(\theta, \phi)&=(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi)\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} \\
&=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{1-z^2}\\
&=\frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}.
\end{split}$$
This is not a polynomial. Therefore, it is not a finite linear combination of spherical harmonics. It must possess nonzero spherical harmonics coefficients of arbitrarily high order, as observed numerically.